# Fetching table from website using QueryTables in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, web

Hi friends,

I am trying to fetch a table from a website using QueryTables in Excel.

I have written the following code

```
With 

ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=SBIN&instrument=OPTSTK&strike=300.00&type=CE&expiry=29JUN2017", Destination:=Range("A10"))
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True    
End With
```

The problem is data is not appearing.I am just getting the column headings.

Here is a snapshot of what I am getting

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually do a Data, From web from within Excel, you get similar results. This is due to the limitations of the webquery feature of Excel, which doesn't handle sites using scripts to fetch the data very well.

Comment: So is there any other alternative to fetch data from tables ?

Comment: Yes, the new Get and transform add-in (if you have 2016 it is built-in) handles this site better.